# set india as default country flag country_picker flutter?

Tags: flutter, picker, country

I am working with a flutter project and there is a dropdown menu that shows all the countries as a default. It shows Afghanistan, but I want to show India as default:

```
CountryPickerDropdown(
                                            onTap: () =>
                                                FocusScope.of(context)
                                                    .requestFocus(
                                                    FocusNode()),
                                            onValuePicked: (
                                                Country country) {
                                              print("${country.name}");
                                            },
                                            itemBuilder: (Country country) {
                                              return Row(
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  CountryPickerUtils
                                                      .getDefaultFlagImage(
                                                      country),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      country.isoCode,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              );
                                            },
                                            itemHeight: null,
                                            isExpanded: true,
                                            icon: SizedBox(),
                                          )
```

Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to pass `countryFilter` argument with India as first item.

Comment: can you tell me how?

Comment: you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57869593/set-default-value-for-dropdown-button-in-flutter)

Comment: @CodingBee checked the source code. countryFilter won't work. The plugin doesn't provide comparable where you could have set order of countries.

Comment: @CodingBee you can raise a ticket on plugin github project or fix it yourself and raise a PR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code hope its helpful to you. just Set `initialValue` used `country_pickers` package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/country_pickers)

Your Widget:

```
CountryPickerDropdown(
    initialValue: 'in',
    itemBuilder: _buildDropdownItem,
    onValuePicked: (Country country) {
         print("${country.name}");
      },
),
```

Your method:

```
Widget _buildDropdownItem(Country country) => Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            CountryPickerUtils.getDefaultFlagImage(country),
            SizedBox(
              width: 8.0,
            ),
            Text("+${country.phoneCode}(${country.isoCode})"),
          ],
        ),
      );
```

Your result screen-> [image]